# Embed javascript file in ajax results

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wrote an ajax code like this :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: {id:id},
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                    $('.post').html(result);
            }
       });
```

this code show more post in the `index.php` file , when it shows the more posts `main.js` file that embeded in the `index.php` not working on the new posts.

i used this code in the `post.php` :

```
   <script src="main.js" ></script>
```

it worked but some of the function run two time.

how can i embed the `main.js` on the `post.php` without the above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-run those function on ajax response thats are needed for new posts.
You don't have to call full main.js file again.

Or if you have any click event write like below.

```
$(document).on("click", '.selector', function(){
    //Here will be your code
});
```

You can use any event instead of click.

Comment: what is the difference between above code and $(".selector").click(function(){ //codes }); , first work but this not.

Comment: @DanielJames The code in the answer will work for dynamically-created `.selector` elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: `$(".selector")` search `.selector` when first time page load, and if you use `$(document)` it will search on full DOM every time.